# Disabling a JavaScript function with a Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am working on a mobile part of my site and I would like to disable a welcome message which is produced by a JavaScript function when the page loads.

What I am trying to do is to disable that function with a cookie that has the expiration time of 20 minutes.

This is how far I've gotten with the cookie:

```
// c_name = cookie name
// c_value = cookie value
// ex_min = expiration in minutes
function setCookie(c_name, c_value, ex_min) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (ex_min*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value + "; " + expires;
}
// Cookie that lasts for 20 minutes.
setCookie("last-visited", "1", 20);
```

What I can't figure out is how to disable that function from within the cookie.

And yes, the cookie is from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use setInterval function

Comment: How long would you like the message to be disabled? Forever or until User leaves your site by closing the tab/window?
Anyway the imaginary "showWelcome" would read the cookie and not show if the cookie exists. If the cookie did not exist and message was shown, the cookie is set.

Comment: @tiblu, what I wanna do is to get the message to show up once when the user visits the page, and when the cookie is sent, then the message is disabled for the user for a 20 minute period.

Comment: @UltraAlkaline see Daniel Grankin's answer. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need something like this

```
var lastVisitedCookieName = 'last-visited';
if (!document.cookie.contains(lastVisitedCookieName))
{
    alert('Welcome');
    setCookie(lastVisitedCookieName, "1", 20);
}
```

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!